# Creating link to Outlook messages

Tags: outlook

**`Outlook 2007`**

While composing a new message in outlook can a link be created to other messages?

Whww I am composing a new mail I would like to create a link to asent item, clicking this link should then open the message.

Can this be done?

Comment: I found two links that are suitable to this question

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/types-of-hyperlinks-HP005242804.aspx
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/insert-a-hyperlink-HP003082185.aspx

Comment: These links do not work any more, unfortunately

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft has a support KB on hyperlinks to access Outlook folders and items: 
http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/158135

However, the Outlook: scheme is not registered by default with newer versions of outlook.
http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/using-outlook-links/

I verified that the registry editing technique to associate "outlook:" with opening Outlook items ( http://www.slipstick.com/problems/outlook-missing-outlook-protocol/ ) works for Outlook 2013 on Windows 8.1, so I imagine it would work for earlier versions too.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to do the same thing in Outlook 2013. I was able to do so without any registry editing. (I believe such editing is only necessary if you want the links to work outside of Outlook)

I wanted to create a link to an email that I had stored in the following Outlook folder: `My Projects\Set 1\`. The subject line of the email was `Testing links`. Here's the steps to do so:

1. Right-click on the folder in which the target email is stored -> Choose **Properties...**
2. Copy the full Location path (in my case this was `\\MyEmail@my.domain\My Projects`. (Note that this doesn't include the parent folder itself; Use the description box (or some other convenient location) to paste that path, then append the folder. So in my case the full path looked like `\\MyEmail@my.domain\My Projects\Set 1`.
3. Open up the email that you want to paste the link into.
4. Create a [normal hyperlink](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Add-a-hyperlink-to-an-email-message-48780838-1b3d-4def-8612-03100491024c)
5. In the **Address** field type `Outlook:` followed by the path you created in Step 2 above, followed by a backslash and tilde, followed by the subject line of the target email. So for me, that whole address looks like this: `Outlook:\\MyEmail@my.domain\My Projects\~Testing links`
6. Done.